# How can I tell if a Spark job is successful or not?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to do some clean-ups after a Spark job is finished, and the action I would do depends on whether the job is successful or not.

So how where can I get the result for the job?

I already tried the `SparkListener`, it worked fine when the job is successful, but if the job fails, the listener seems not called.

Comment: please check this [document](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST API of the Spark HistoryServer to check the state of the job.
Here you can find all information that you need:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html